# R transform data with multiple values

Tags: r, transform

I'm trying to transform my data so that each keyword has a value rather than grouped by value. My data is currently organized like this:

df:

```
score1 score2 keyword1 keyword2 keyword3
.2    .4    brown    fox    jump
.7    .2    hello    bye    
.1    .9    foo
```

I would like my data to look like this:

```
keyword score1 score2
brown    .2    .4     
fox    .2    .4    
jump    .2    .4    
hello    .7    .2    
bye    .7    .2   
foo    .1    .9
```

data:

```
df = structure(list(score1 = c(.2, .7, .1), score2 = c(.4, .2, .9), keyword1 = c("brown", "hello", "foo"), keyword2 = c("fox", "bye"), keyword3 = "jump"), .Names = c("score1", "score2", "keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative using `gather()` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(label, keyword, -(score1:score2), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
#   score1 score2    label keyword
#1     0.2    0.4 keyword1   brown
#2     0.7    0.2 keyword1   hello
#3     0.1    0.9 keyword1     foo
#6     0.2    0.4 keyword2     fox
#7     0.7    0.2 keyword2     bye
#11    0.2    0.4 keyword3    jump
```

Optionally, you could remove the `label` column by adding `select(-label)` to the chain.

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(score1 = c(0.2, 0.7, 0.1, NA, NA), score2 = c(0.4, 
0.2, 0.9, NA, NA), keyword1 = c("brown", "hello", "foo", NA, 
NA), keyword2 = c("fox", "bye", NA, NA, NA), keyword3 = c("jump", 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("score1", "score2", "keyword1", 
"keyword2", "keyword3"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one method using `melt` from the `data.table` package:

```
# drop some missing obs
df <- df[1:3, ]
# create ID variable
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

# load data.table
library(data.table)
# reshape long (melt)
newdf <- melt(df, id.vars=c("id", "score1", "score2"), 
     measure.vars=c("keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"), value.name="keyword")
```

Although not necessary in the example, I added an id variable so that this method will work on larger datasets to cover the case where score1 and score2 may be identical for multiple observations. This creates two more columns than in your example, the id column and a column with "keyword1" and so on. It is easy enough to drop these. In addition, there are some rows present that are NA, do to the non-rectangular shape of the input data. These may be dropped with `is.na`:

```
# drop rows with missing values in keyword column
newdf <- newdf[!is.na(newdf$keyword),]
```

Comment: I liked your answer, I have a question. I have been busy with R for almost a year but I don't see any progress. how do you work with R ?

Comment: Many hours, lots of years: progress can be slow. Most important: spend extra time taking apart working code to see what each piece does. Read help files of functions you don't understand. Learn about object types and what object types are required by a specific function.